# Is there an Angular 2 equivalent to Angular1's $location.absURL()?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there a way to return the full url representation with all segments encoded using Angular 2?

According to the Angular 1 Documentation, $location.absUrl(); will return it as such.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

> Methods absUrl(); This method is getter only.
>
> Return full url representation with all segments encoded according to
>   rules specified in RFC 3986.
>
> ```
> // given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo 
> var absUrl = $location.absUrl();  
> // => "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately the closest I could find was injecting Location and then doing: this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path()), which returns everything except the "http://example.com"

Comment: @RobLouie is there an example of this sort of code in use anywhere? I need to do exactly what you have here, but I'm having trouble with how and where to import "location".

Comment: I don't know of an example of this exact use case, but there is an example of injecting and using location in the Angular 2 docs: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html.

Answer (score 5):

```
import {LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location:LocationStrategy) {
  var fullPath = (<any>this.location)._platformLocation.location.href;
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. But is there a 'proper' way of getting this? The Cast to any is a little bit hack

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>


import {LocationStrategy} from  '@angular/common'
// pre RC.2 import {LocationStrategy} from  'angular2/router'

constructor(private location:LocationStrategy) {
  this.location.prepareExternalUrl('http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo');
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/OWwl8n?p=preview)